# Intelligent folder in windows using batch file to copy files

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp, directory, copy-paste

I would like to move a file from dir1 to dir2 if its size is not changing anymore (fully processed). A possible attend would be to ask size0(at 0s) and size10(at 10s) and if size0=size10 than move file from dir1 to dir2.

How to do it in command line on windows xp?

Comment: You can have a script, not a CLI command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "file=C:\path\to\your.file"
set "destination=D:\some\folder"

:loop
call :GetSize "%file%" s1
call :Sleep 10
call :GetSize "%file%" s2
if %s1% neq %s2% goto loop

call :MoveUnlessExists "%file%"

goto :eof

:GetSize
set "%~2=%~z1"
goto :eof

:Sleep
set /a "n=%1+1"
ping -n %n% 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto :eof

:MoveUnlessExists
if not exist "%destination%\%~nx1" move "%~f1" "%destination%\"
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. The ping step is just for pending, so I could also use something else to pause?

Comment: @Denis Yes. If you have an actual `sleep` command at hand you can drop the entire `:Sleep` "subroutine".

Comment: Great, thank you. An additional question: What should I add if I only want to copy files from dir1 to dir2 which are not already in dir2? Is there a trivial way to do it?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. However it seems not to work in this version. The last section includes "%%~f1" which I changed to %file% and afterwards it seems to work. But now it seems still to copy the file no matter if exist or not...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My mistake. Habitual doubling of `%` characters. It must be `%~nx1` and `%~f1`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
CD /d dir1
:loop
FOR %%a IN (file) DO SET "size=%%~za"
PING -n 10 localhost >NUL
FOR %%a IN (file) DO IF %%~za equ %size% (move "%%~a" dir2) ELSE GOTO :loop
```

Comment: This worked as well. It seems to be more elegant but also harder to understand :) I apologize for not accepting your answer, however thank you for your help.

Comment: +1  Though %size% is never being updated so the file will never be copied - or have I misunderstood?  It should monitor the changing size and copy when it remains static.